# Integration of struts2 with Liferay?

Tags: java, liferay

I made a sample application to integrate struts2 with liferay. But the problem arises when the setter method in the Action class doesn't get invoked. I am passing parameters through the struts form to the Action class but when I am printing those values through `welcome.jsp` I am getting values as null for `name` and 0 for `id`. Here is my code for form:-

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s" %>

<s:form action="product">  
<s:textfield name="id" label="Product Id"></s:textfield>  
<s:textfield name="name" label="Product Name"></s:textfield>  
<s:textfield name="price" label="Product Price"></s:textfield>  
<s:submit value="save"></s:submit>  
</s:form>
```

The code for struts.xml is as follows:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>  
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts  
Configuration 2.1//EN" "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.1.dtd">  
<struts>  
<constant name="struts.objectFactory.spring.autoWire" value="type" />
<package name="view" namespace="/view" extends="struts-portlet-default">  

  <action name="product" class="com.abhishek.Product" method="execute">  

<result name="success">/welcome.jsp</result>  
</action>  

<action name="index"
            class="com.abhishek.Product">
            <result name="success">/index.jsp</result>
        </action>


</package>  

</struts>
```

The code for Product.java is as follows:-

```
package com.abhishek;  

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionContext;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletRequestAware;

public class Product extends ActionSupport implements ServletRequestAware {  
/**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
/**
     * 
     */
    HttpServletRequest request;
    private int id;  
private String name;  
private float price;  
public int getId() {  
    return id;  
}  
public void setId(int id) {  
    this.id = id;  
}  
public String getName() {
       return name;  
}  
public void setName(String name) {  
    System.out.println("Inside setName");
    this.name = name;  
}  
public float getPrice() {  
    return price;  
}  
public void setPrice(float price) {  
    this.price = price;  
}  

public String execute(){
    System.out.println("name is"+ ActionContext.getContext().getParameters().get("name"));
    System.out.println("name="+name);
    return "success";  
} 

public String execute1(){  
    return "success";  
}
@Override
public void setServletRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    this.request=request;
} 

public HttpServletRequest getServletRequest()
{
    return this.request;
}

}
```

The code for welcome.jsp is as follows:-

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@ taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s" %>  

Product Id:<s:property value="id"/><br/>  
Product Name:<s:property value="name"/><br/>  
Product Price:<s:property value="price"/><br/>
```

I want to ask if it is really be possible to integrate struts2 application with liferay and if so why does setter method not get invoked?I have already made a couple of applications in struts2 in liferay but came with same problem..So please help..any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking the parameter value without reading using getParameter("yourParameter") method. Check if they are printed correctly, otherwise your model itself not initialized properly.

Comment: i already did that and the model is not initialized..thats what I want to know why is the model not initialized?Why are setter methods not invoked to initialize model? Please help..thanx in advance.

Comment: what is the work environment, i mean Java version and struts2 and server? Cause that also make things go wrong sometime.